# How to create Demo bar for HTML Templates with Next botton and automatic finding folders?

Tags: javascript, php, directory

I have some HTML Template and I want show them in `iFrame`, some of this Template have 2 to 11 colors variety.

```
folder name ex.
1
2
3
3-1
3-2
3-3
3-4
3-5
4
5
6-1
6-2
7
and more...
```

**I have a botton for show NEXT template.**

I want use `is_dir` in php to check if directory 1 or 3-2 is available then show it.

```
<?php

$id = $_GET['id'];

$c=$id+1;
$c1=$c."-1";

$xm=$c;
$xm1=$c1;   

if (is_dir($xm)) {
    $c=$c;  
}

if (is_dir($xm1)) {$c=$c1;}

?>

<div id="header-bar">
    <form method="get" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $c ?>">
        <input type="submit" value="NEXT">
    </form>
</div>

<iframe src="http://barg.ir/demo/<?php echo $id; ?>"></iframe>
```

Question1: I can show folder 3-1 but I cant show folder 3-2 and 3-3 and..., how do this?

Question2: can coding with php array?

Question3: can coding with JavaScript? what is equal `is_dir` in javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you look into using `glob()`? Put the following into the folder you want to get the information from:

```
// we'll call it grabber.php
<?php
$files = glob('*', GLOB_ONLYDIR); sort($files, SORT_NATURAL);
?>

// now you can include grabber.php in your form file
<?php
session_start(); include_once 'PATH/grabber.php'; $end = count($files)-1;
<div id='header-bar'>
  <form method='post' action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>'>
    <input type='submit' value='BACK' name='back' />
    <input type='submit' value='NEXT' name='next' />
  </form>
if(isset($_POST['back'])){
  $_SESSION['fileNum']--;
  if($_SESSION['fileNum'] < 0)$_SESSION['fileNum'] = $end;
}
elseif(isset($_POST['next'])){
  $_SESSION['fileNum']++;
  if($_SESSION['fileNum'] > $end)$_SESSION['fileNum'] = 0;
}
else{
  $_SESSION['fileNum'] = 0;
}
$f = $files[$_SESSION['fileNum']];
echo "  <iframe src='http://barg.ir/demo/$f'></iframe>".
'</div>';
?>
```

Obviously `PATH` needs to be changed.

Better yet use JavaScript:

```
// You'll still need `grabber.php` in the same location as before, only now
// we'll actually make the PHP page into a String for JavaScript usage, like:
<?php
$dirs = glob('*', GLOB_ONLYDIR); sort($dirs, SORT_NATURAL);
$dirsJS = implode("', '", $dirs); // implode into a String for JavaScript Array
echo "//<![CDATA[
var doc = document, bod = doc.body;
bod.className = 'js'; // use .njs class in CSS for users without JavaScript
function E(e){
  return doc.getElementById(e);
}
function direct(backId, nextId, iframeId, iframeSrcBase){
  var dirs = ['$dirsJS'];
  var dl = dirs.length-1, n = 0, f = E(iframeId), s = iframeSrcBase;
  f.src = s+dirs[0];
  E(backId).onclick = function(){
    if(--n < 0)n = dl;
    f.src = s+dirs[n];
  }
  E(nextId).onclick = function(){
    if(++n > dl)n = 0;
    f.src = s+dirs[n];
  }
}
//]]>";
?>

/* 
   Now back to your main page. I like XHTML, but you can use whatever.
   The reason for JavaScript is to avoid scrolling issues and page flashing
   This is your main page again without as much PHP. There's no need to
   include the other file in PHP, or use a session. We use the `script`
   tag instead. Pay attention:
*/
<?php
echo "<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
      <style type='text/css'>
        @import 'yourCSS.css';
      </style>
    </head>
  <body class='njs'>
    <div id='header-bar'>
      <form method='post' action='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}'>
        <input type='button' value='BACK' name='back' id='back' />
        <input type='button' value='NEXT' name='next' id='next' />
      </form>
      <iframe id='ifr' src=''><noscript>Your Browser Does Not Support JavaScript</noscript></iframe>
    </div>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='PATH/grabber.php'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      direct('back', 'next', 'ifr', 'http://barg.ir/demo/');
    </script>
  </body>
  </html>";
?>
```

Once again, this time in the `script` tag, change `PATH` accordingly.

Comment: no... are you see the themeforest.net? we need only one iFrame in Demo page that show us Template1, if click in Next botton the iFrame will be show Template2.

Comment: what is glob('*.php'); ?

Comment: I have not php Template! I have 100 Folder, that in each folder have one HTML Template with index.html

Comment: what is grabber.php ?

Comment: we want show only folder in iFrame because index.html will display automatically. (path/1/    path/2/    and more...)

Comment: Do you have access to the directory containing the other directories?

Comment: yes, I access to all directories, but I need show path/1/ not showing path/index1.html

Comment: Look at `glob()` again. Personally, I would use AJAX to avoid screen flashes.

Comment: I have not grabber.php !

Comment: Well, you'll have to MAKE IT. Just copy and paste the code into a text editor, save it as `grabber.php`, then put it in your directory that contains other directories. It's just this line of code `<?php $files = glob('*', GLOB_ONLYDIR); ?>`.

Comment: ok, I understand, but when I click next button show me template 1 again!

Comment: I forgot the `name` attribute. Try now.

Comment: I fixed it. $_SESSION was resetting to 0, every time page loaded.

Comment: excuse me, after 1 displaying 10, or after 2 displaying 20

Comment: I thing must rename all folders to 001,002,... or can coding that I not have to rename folders?

Comment: create new iFrame in iFrame!

Comment: Syntax, `'` missing at `$f>`

Comment: ini_set('display_errors', '0');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

Comment: I testing in easyphp (localhost)

Comment: JS was helpful but someone may be disable SESSION or JavaScript, can you coding with only $_GET , I need showing ID in url like this `http://barg.ir/demo/index.html?id=3`

Comment: Use the first example. Change `<form method='post'` to `<form method='get'`, and `$_POST['back']` to `$_GET['back']`, and `$_POST['next']` to `$_GET['next']`.